# longest decreasing sublist inside a given list

Tags: python, list, sequence

I wanted to find the longest decreasing sub sequence inside a given list for example L = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1], the result should be [2,1] however I cant seem to produce that result. Can someone tell me why it doesn't work ? The output is something [0,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1] Nevermind the first zero but the result should produce [2,1].

Here's a code I tried

```
L = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]

current = [0]
smallest = []

for i in  range(len(L)):
    if i < (len(L)-1):
        if L[i] >= L[i+1]:
            current.append(L[i])

        else :    
            if L[i] < current[-1]:
                current.append(L[i])

    elif i>= (len(L)-1):
        if L[-1]<L[i-1]:
            current.append(L[i])
    else:
        current = [i]
    if len(current) > len(smallest):
            smallest = current
```

Result : [0,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1]

Desired Result : [2,1]

Comment: `if len(current) > len(smallest)` in here, smallest is not defined at this point. Does it even compile?

Comment: Sorry, The  code is a part of a larger ode but everything else worked fine so I didnt see the need to post the whole porgram and in the process I missed the part where I declared the smallest as a empty list. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: SHould be decreasing by 1 only, or any decreasing sequence is good?

Comment: Any sub sequence that decreases is fine for example if L = [7,8,1,2,3,4,77,78,58,2] then result should be [77,78,58,2] since it is the largest sequence  that continuously decreases

Comment: Then SSj.Luffy anwser is good one, so can check it out.

Comment: `77,78` is an increase did you mean `[78,58,2]`.

Comment: Sorry about that, yes I meant [78,58,2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you say `current = [0]`, it actually adds `0` to the list, maybe you want `current = [L[0]]`.
See this:

```
def longest_decreasing_sublist(a):
  lds, current = [], [a[0]]
  for val in a[1:]:
    if val < current[-1]: current.append(val)
    else:
      lds = current[:] if len(current) > len(lds) else lds
      current = [val]
  lds = current[:] if len(current) > len(lds) else lds
  return lds

L = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
print (longest_decreasing_sublist(L))
# [2, 1]
```

Comment: Could you explain to me how your code works with a few comments and tell me where MY code is wrong ? suggest edits to my code ?That would be very very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There are so many ways to solve this. In Py3 - using `itertools.accumulate` for dynamic programming:

```
>>> import operator as op
>>> import itertools as it
>>> L = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
>>> dyn = it.accumulate(it.chain([0], zip(L, L[1:])), lambda x, y: (x+1)*(y[0]>y[1]))
>>> i, l = max(enumerate(dyn), key=op.itemgetter(1))
>>> L[i-l:i+1]
[2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off engineering your code for maintainability and readability up front, so that you can easily test components of your software individually rather than trying to solve the entire thing at once. This is known as functional decomposition.

Think about what you need at the topmost level.

First, you need a way to get the longest decreasing subset at a *given* point in the array, so that you can intelligently compare the various sequences.

You can do that with code such as:

```
def getNextSequence(myList, index):
    # Beyond list end, return empty list.

    if index > len(myList):
        return []

    # Construct initial list, keep adding until either
    # an increase is found or no elements left.

    sequence = [ myList[index] ]
    addIdx = index + 1
    while addIdx < len(myList) and myList[addIdx] <= myList[addIdx - 1]:
        sequence.append(myList[addIdx])
        addIdx += 1

    # And there you have it, the sequence at a given point.

    return sequence
```

Second, you need to be able to store the current longest one and check the lengths to see whether the current one is greater than the longest to date.

That breaks down to something like:

```
def getLongestSequence(myList):
    # Initially no sequence, even a sequence of one
    # will beat this.

    longestSequence = []

    # This index is where we are checking. Keep checking
    # until all possibilities exhausted.

    checkIndex = 0
    while checkIndex < len(myList):
        # Get current sequence, save it if it's longer
        # than the currently longest one.

        currentSequence = getNextSequence(myList, index)
        if len(currentSequence) > len(longestSequence):
            longestSequence = currentSequence

        # Adjust index to next checking point.

        checkIndex += len(currentSequence)

    # All done, just return the longest sequence.

    return longestSequence
```

The important thing there (other than readability, of course) is the changing of the index. Once you've established a decreasing sequence, you *never* need to look anywhere inside it since any partial sequence within it will naturally be shorter than the whole.

In other words, if you have `8, 7, 6, 5, 9`, a sequence starting at `7` *cannot* be (by definition) longer than the sequence starting at `8`. Hence you can skip straight to the `9`.

Comment: Thank you for this, this has really helped me a lot.